# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Container\Container::getLocale() | Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Unit tests are more difficult for me than functional tests, and I am trying to write a unit test that relates to my middleware, but what goes wrong. Can someone help me fix this error, or write a normal unit test for this middleware.

My middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Services\SettingsService;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

final class Locale
{
    private SettingsService $settingsService;

    public function __construct(SettingsService $settingsService)
    {
        $this->settingsService = $settingsService;
    }

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): mixed
    {
        $locale = $this->settingsService->get('language', app()->getLocale());
        app()->setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

my test

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Http\Middleware\Locale;
use App\Services\SettingsService;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class LocaleMiddlewareTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_example()
    {
        $request = new Request;

        $settingsService = $this->getMockBuilder(SettingsService::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
        $middleware = new Locale($settingsService);

        $middleware->handle($request, function ($req) {
            $this->assertEquals('en', app()->getLocale());
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use `Tests\TestCase` instead of `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`

```
//use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
use Tests\TestCase;

class LocaleMiddlewareTest extends TestCase{


//.... other code
}
```

Comment: Ah, just load the whole framework for a unit test, got it